# While Binding Flot Pie Chart its not visible even if data is there

Tags: jquery, flot

I am binding Flot Pie Chart using $.ajax method. while binding i am getting the data in json format and using $.plot method. But after that i cant see the pie chart being plotted. Below is my code:

```
    function drawPieChart() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Api/ChartsApi.aspx",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            if (r != null) {
                data = r;
                DrawPieChart();

            }
            else {
                alert("No Data Avaliable");
                return false;
            }
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
    });
}

//Pie Chart
function DrawPieChart() {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            labelBoxBorderColor: "none"
        }
    });
}
```

Data is Below:

```
[ { "Status": "Active", "Count": 28 }, { "Status": "Under Process", "Count": 15 }, { "Status": "Registered", "Count": 23 } ]
```

Comment: How does your `data` look like? If it's in the wrong format, flot will show an empty chart.

Comment: Data is Below:[
  {
    "Status": "Active",
    "Count": 28
  },
  {
    "Status": "Under Process",
    "Count": 15
  },
  {
    "Status": "Registered",
    "Count": 23
  }
] I am using NewtonSoft.JSON.Net20 dll for converting server side datatabe to json i.e var vjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objdt, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                        Response.Write(vjson);

Answer (score 1):

Your data has the wrong format, flot doesn't know what "Status" and "Count" mean.

Change your data to use `label` and `data`:

```
[ 
    { label: "Active", data: 28 },
    { label: "Under Process", data: 15 },
    { label: "Registered", data: 23 }
]
```

Comment: [
  {
    "label": "Active",
    "Value": 28
  },
  {
    "label": "Under Process",
    "Value": 15
  },
  {
    "label": "Registered",
    "Value": 23
  }
]  Still The Same Issue :(

Comment: Hi Raidri, Actually whats happening is now the data is coming but its getting visible when we clicked the search button and then its not visible. Means its getting visible only for a second and getting off.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it should be `data` instead of `value`. Strange that you see it for a second.

Comment: [
  {
    "label": "Active",
    "data": 28
  },
  {
    "label": "Under Process",
    "data": 15
  },
  {
    "label": "Registered",
    "data": 23
  }
] Yes this is working but its getting visible for half a second like just a blink. What should be the reason?

Comment: That's a strange problem I never had before. Any messages in the console? Maybe another AJAX call coming back a second later?

Comment: Hi Raidri, Thanks for your solution. I added return false; after my method and that worked. My page was getting post back due to which could not see the pie chart. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79778/discussion-between-rahul-and-raidri).